# How to get outlook rest push notification when I get new email in an email conversation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

As per [Outlook Push Notifications Rest API referance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations) documentation `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages` is resource url that we need to use for subscribing email notification. Now I want to get push notification when ever there is an new email in email conversation. Does Outlook push notification supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can express the conversation with a filter expression, you can use the push notification filtering properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations#RefineConditionsV2

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Could you please provide more detail like which filter i have to use?  It would be very helpfully if you can provide the entire resource url that i can be used while make push notification subscription API call.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the API myself, so I can't help you out there.